# an element in $\prod_n M_n(\Bbb C)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I want to find an element $x=(x_n)\in \prod_nM_n(\Bbb C)$ such that $\lim \operatorname{tr}_n(x_n)=0$ but $\lim \operatorname{tr}_n(x_n^*x_n)\not \to 0$,where $tr$ is the unique tracial state on $M_n(\Bbb C)$.But I cannot think of an example for a while.I'll appreciate it anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the bounded sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ given by 
$$
\begin{cases}
 x_{2n} := 1_n \oplus (-1_n), \\
 x_{2n+1} := 1_{2n+1}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\mathrm{tr}_n(x_n) = 0$  for every even natural nuber $n$. Now, let $\omega$ be a free ultrafilter such that $\omega$ contains the set of all even natural numbers. Then you easily check that 
$$
 \lim_\omega \mathrm{tr}_n(x_n) = 0, 
$$
but
$$
\lim_\omega \mathrm{tr}_n(x_n^*x_n) = 1.
$$

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can take $x_n$ to be the shift, that is $x_n=\sum_{j=1}^n E_{j,j+1}$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(x_n)=0$ for all $n$, while $\operatorname{tr}(x_n^*x_n)=1-\tfrac1n$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{tr}(x_n^*x_n)=1,$$
while $$\operatorname{tr}(x_n)=0$$ for all $n$.